# Binding Param in a UNION ALL with Two Selects and different WHERE Clauses

Tags: php, mysql

I have combined two select queries with union all and two different set of WHERE clauses. How do I bind the params to the different WHERE statements?

This is my query below:

```
$curdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$year = "2024";
$month = "12";
$day = "03";
$paystat = "Paid";
$paymtstat = "Pending";

$query = "(SELECT ukimID, screeningdate, paymentstatus, regdeadlinetime
            FROM ukmedscreening 
            WHERE YEAR(screeningdate)=? 
            AND MONTH(screeningdate)=? 
            AND DAY(screeningdate)=? 
            AND regdeadlinetime>?)
    UNION ALL
        (SELECT ukimID, screeningdate, paymentstatus, regdeadlinetime 
        FROM ukmedscreening 
        WHERE YEAR(screeningdate)=? 
        AND MONTH(screeningdate)=? 
        AND DAY(screeningdate)=? 
        AND regdeadlinetime<? 
        AND paymentstatus=?)";

$stmt = $connQlife->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $year, $month, $day, $curdate); <- Param 1
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $year, $month, $day, $curdate, $paystat); <-Param 2
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($ukimID, $screeningdate, $paymentstatus, $regdeadlinetime);
$stmt->fetch();
$totalnumrows = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->close();
```

This gives a blank result. I know with UNION or UNION ALL, the columns must be the same with the same datatype. But where I have the issue is with the WHERE conditions using prepared statements. Must they also be the same number? As i have highlighted, the 2 params, 1 & 2 are not the same in number of parameters.

Can I use only one bind_param? and if yes, how do I do it when the WHERE conditions are not the same in number?

Comment: bind_param has nothing to do with unions or select.  you have a statement (that happens to be a union of selects) that has 9 parameters, just give it those 9 parameters.

Comment: @ysth something like this: $stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $year, $month, $day, $curdate, $year, $month, $day, $curdate, $paystat);

Comment: What do you mean by "blank result"? Is there an error or exception? There should be.

Comment: Whats difficult? It's all one query, so add up the `?` and pass a relevant parameter for each one on a single call to `$stmt->bind_param()`

Comment: Using PDO would be easier. No binding needed, just pass an array of parameters to `PDOStatement::execute()` as shown in several of the examples: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php